# Arduino: print on the serial change my values

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm very new to Arduino. I have a simple arduino+bluethooth module and I want to read the values sent by an Android phone. I can read values but I got weird results when doing stuff with those values. here's the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rx 10
#define tx 11

SoftwareSerial BtSerial(rx,tx);


void setup ()
{
  pinMode(rx, INPUT);
  pinMode(tx, OUTPUT);

  //setup bt connection
  BtSerial.begin (38400);

  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop ()
{ 
  int command = 0;
    while(BtSerial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                int incomingByte = BtSerial.read();

                // say what you got:
                Serial.print("I received: ");
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
                command+=incomingByte;
        }
    if(command>0){
      Serial.print("sum:");
      Serial.println(command, DEC);
    }
    switch(command){
      case 3090:
        Serial.println("avanti");
        break;
      case 5599:
        Serial.println("avanti destra");
        break;
      case 2266:
        Serial.println("destra");
        break;
      case 5649:
        Serial.println("indietro destra");
        break;
      case 3140:
        Serial.println("indietro");
        break;
      case 5066:
        Serial.println("indietro sinistra");
        break;
      case 1747:
        Serial.println("sinistra");
        break;
      case 5016:
        Serial.println("avanti sinistra");
        break;
      case 1734:
        Serial.println("stop");
        break;
      }
}
```

This code works, when I send a command from the phone I see a certain number of "I received: xxx", one "sum: xxxx" and one of the strings inside the `case` depending on the value of `command`.

the problems comes if I comment those two lines:

```
Serial.print("I received: ");
Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
```

I expected to see one "sum: xxxx" and one of the strings, instead I see some lines with "sum: xxx" and no case is selected from the switch.

what am I missing?

thanks

EDIT: here's an explicit example: I send a certain value from android, with the code above, this is what i get on the serial monitor:

```
I received: 128
I received: 128
I received: 120
I received: 254
I received: 248
I received: 120
I received: 224
I received: 128
I received: 120
I received: 254
I received: 248
I received: 120
I received: 30
I received: 0
I received: 120
I received: 224
I received: 128
I received: 120
I received: 0
I received: 128
I received: 248
sum:3090
avanti
```

if I comment the mentioned lines and send the same value this is what I get:

```
sum:128
sum:502
sum:720
sum:772
sum:472
sum:248
sum:248
```

Comment: Write switch block to inside of if statement. I mean; close if stament`if(command>0){` after switch-case block. It should solve your problem as I understand.

Comment: I added an example to the question, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @TOMATO I solved it. it looks like printing on the serial adds a delay, so I removed the prints and added an explicit minimum delay:

```
 while(BtSerial.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte:
                int incomingByte = BtSerial.read();

                // say what you got:
                //Serial.print("I received: ");
                //Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
                command+=incomingByte;
                delay(5);
        }
```